# 'Conditional Options' in columns 

Tags: site-column

Is there an option for 'Conditional Options' in choice type of columns. i.e. if India is selected in 'country' column then Indian states are reflected as options in the next column called 'states', but if country selected is USA - then options in state column changes to USA states.

Is there a solution for above feature?

thx!

---saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to create a series of Cascade choice field in a SharePoint list, there is no such functionality OOTB. There is a number of community solutions with various technologies involved like: [code (C#)](http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com/), [javascript/JQuery](http://www.uccorner.com/54/sharepoint/cascading-drop-down/) and [InfoPath](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/12/31/infopath-cascading-drop-down-screencast/).

You should probably start with [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) that has implementation of Cascade Dropdown with JQuery and nice tutorial about that.

Comment: Check SPServices Library, there is a link in my original answer.

Comment: Cascade list with filter works nicely. Thx Toni